# how to test for equality between objects with common superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a virtual class called `X` and subclasses `X1` `X2` and `X3`.

*Clarification: these classes are dumb data: `int`, `double`, `string`, `vector<>` of the preceding.  There may be pointers to read-only static data structures whereby equality is a shallow check that the pointers be equal.  There won't be for instance `FILE*` where it there are many ways you to decide an open file is equal.*

I have two pointers of type `X*` that in fact point to subclasses.

What's the easiest way to check for equality?

Just to show I've put some work into it, my plan is: give `X` a virtual method `IsEqual()` that takes a `X* pxThat`.  Each subclass implements this method.  The method would use a `dynamic_cast<>` to see if the argument is its own class and if not report `false`.  Otherwise it would used the dynamically-cast argument to check equality field by field.

Still, I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do it?

Comment: Don't go and invent your own names when [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) is already right there. Dynamic casting shouldn't be relevant because unless you're using template functions nothing "bad" will ever be supplied as arguments.

Comment: What is the definition of IsEqual? Same instance? Same data members? You really should post some code.

Comment: @tadman can I make operator== virtual?  Didn't know that.  Or if I can't, how would it work?

Comment: @tadman and if I don't use `dynamic_cast<>`, then I have a pointer to the base class.  And in that case how do I compare it to `this`?

Comment: You need to give a more concrete example. Comparing two different classes this way is highly situational.

Comment: Equality comparison does not usually make sense for polymorphic objects. When it does, it is very application specific. The way you have done it is problematic because it breaks [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (in other words, it breaks old code when a new class is introduced).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: didn't know LSP before, interesting, thx.  In this case X1 X2 X3 are terminal subclasses and won't be further subclassed, so I see nothing that could break.   E.g., x2a == x2b if true remains true if a class X4 is added.

Comment: @tadman thx, added clarification of contents

Comment: In your case inheritance may or may not be the right tool for the job. I would try `std::variant` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, often the virtual methods are public.

There is an idiom that some C++ programs use where the base class public methods are not virtual, and it is used to call a private virtual method.  The rationale for this approach is that it separates out the public facing API from the derived class extensibility API (the virtual), rather than having the public facing API and the derived class API entangled and commingled.  It is called the [non-virtual interface idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

It appears to me that with your given problem, it is a good place to utilize the *non-virtual interface idiom*.  Because it makes the non-virtual `X::operator==` implementation cleaner and the virtual `isEqual` cleaner and simpler, otherwise it could get pretty convoluted.

`isEqual()` is only called by `operator==`, and only when that operator has determined the class matches.  Since this is guaranteed, the `isEqual()` implementation in the subclasses is best done with `static_cast`, which is slightly faster than `dynamic_cast`.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>

namespace {

struct X {
    virtual ~X() = default;
    bool operator==(X const&) const;
private:
    // Allow objects of superclass X to be compared, and supply a
    // working method for subclasses who have no additional fields to
    // check to establish equality.
    virtual bool isEqual(X const& rhs) const { return true; };
};

class X1 : public X {
    int a;
    bool isEqual(X const&) const override;
public:
    X1() : a{} {}
    X1(int a_) : a{a_} {}
};

struct X2 : X { };

struct X3 : X { };

bool X::operator==(X const& rhs) const {
    return typeid(*this) == typeid(rhs) && isEqual(rhs);
}

bool X1::isEqual(X const& rhs) const {
    // isEqual MUST only be called if lhs and rhs are the same type.
    auto const& r = static_cast<X1 const&>(rhs);
    return a == r.a;
}

} // namespace anon



int main() {
    X x;
    X1 x1{7};
    X2 x2;
    X3 x3;

    assert(x == X{});
    assert(x1 != X{});
    assert(x2 != X{});
    assert(x3 != X{});
    assert(x1 == X1{7});
    assert(x2 == X2{});
    assert(x3 == X3{});
    assert(x1 != X2{});
    assert(x2 != X3{});
    assert(x3 != X1{});
    assert(x1 != X1{6});
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to edit more than a minimum, but I think the good argument for having a base class normal method and a virtual method is that a portion of the work (the type equality check) can be factored out.  Any time you have something in common between several implementations, it makes sense to factor that out if its easy to do so and in this case it's trivial.

Comment: I think the edits means that this depends on C++20 or later.  I used C++17.  But that's okay.